# FCM error: Service messaging is not available

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyA0dAgRPZLlgULgnOp2MH_3xtVbWPs03Cg",
  authDomain: "u-63f99.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "u-63f99",
  storageBucket: "u-63f99.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "884933400988",
  appId: "1:884933400988:web:0b7e0e37b0f23da236d059",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const fireStore = getFirestore(app);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);
export { auth, fireStore, messaging };
```

[i'm getting this error, i don't know why messaging service is missing while i installed firebase SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJhyx.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your problem is probably because you're testing this on localhost (http).

if you look at the console logs you might notice beside that error something like:
`code: 'messaging/unsupported-browser'`

and cloud messaging only support https connections so you'd have to make your localhost run on https somehow to get it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

When I get this issue in Next.js (localhost) , I searched across the internet and finally I found this solution . The main problem is calling getMessaging in firestore.js , Instead

```
useEffect(() => {
if (
  "Notification" in window &&
  "serviceWorker" in navigator &&
  "PushManager" in window
) {
  const messaging = getMessaging(app);

  requestNotificationPermission();
  const getFCMToken = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey:
          "Your_KEY",
      });
      if (token) {
        console.log("FCM token:", token);
      } else {
        console.log("No FCM token received.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error getting FCM token:", error);
    }
  };
  getFCMToken();
} else {
  console.log("FCM not supported");
}
}, []);
```

This JavaScript code, wrapped in a React useEffect hook, checks if the browser supports notifications and push notifications through Service Workers and the Push Manager. If supported, it initializes a messaging service, requests notification permission, and obtains a Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) token for sending push notifications. If not supported, it logs that FCM is not supported.

PS:  Brave browser needs to enable google push message service in [brave://settings/privacy](https://brave://settings/privacy)